# jQuery Infinite Slider, similar to BBC homepage

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm creating a slideshow, similar to that of the BBC homepage. I have managed to create it so that you can slide left and right, and it will scroll infinitely in a loop. The slide function simply uses an unordered list and prepends or appends the last or first list item to the list.

My problem is that I want to be able to jump to a specific slide... and I just can't think of a good way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var slider = function(transition_time, transition, transition_speed, width){    

    var self = this; var slides = [];

    // Slide left or right
    this.slide = function(direction){

        $('#slideshow-wrapper li').each(function(){
            slides.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });     

        if (direction == 0)                         
            indent =  parseInt($('#slideshow-wrapper').css('left')) + width;        
        else 
            indent =  parseInt($('#slideshow-wrapper').css('left')) - width;

        $('#slideshow-wrapper:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : indent}, transition_speed, transition, function(){    

            if (direction == 0) 
                $('#slideshow-wrapper li:last').detach().fadeIn().prependTo($('#slideshow-wrapper'));

            else
                $('#slideshow-wrapper li:first').detach().fadeIn().appendTo($('#slideshow-wrapper')); 

            $('#slideshow-wrapper').css({'left' : '-' + width + 'px'});
        }); 
    }
}
```

As requested, here is a link to a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TqAdA/21/

Comment: Done, http://jsfiddle.net/TqAdA/21/ .

Comment: Start with one of the many jQuery Slide plugins and customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the BBC do it. Use JQuery and classes.

Have a wrapper div containing your slides which are also divs. So the divs have classes such as :

```
<div class="wrapper>
    <div id="dz-gridsport" class="pane pane-5" style="left: 976px;">
    <div id="dz-gridbbcnow" class="pane pane-0 focused" style="left: 1952px;">
    <div id="dz-gridentertainment" class="pane pane-1" style="left: 2928px;">
</div>
```

So you could get the index of the currently focused slide using :

```
var slideIndex = $(".wrapper").index($(".focused"))
```

Using indexes in such a way, you can then use the widths of each pane and offsets to work out how to get to each pane.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all BBC doesn't use traditional jquery. It uses [GLOW](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) another javascript library.

But you might want to you [nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) instead.

Comment: In know BBC uses glow, but I was hoping to create my own in jQuery. 

I have checked out nivo slider, but I wanted to be able to create entire divs as content, as opposed to just images... and to show previous and next items as masked.

Comment: what about cycle plugin. It is the most flexible one available and comes with a lots of options and has great documentation too.